# Apply() function based on column condition restarting instead of changing

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following apply function:

```
week_to_be_predicted = 15

df['raw_data'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_raw_data(x['boxscore']) if x['week_int']<week_to_be_predicted else 0,axis=1)

df['raw_data'] = df.apply(lambda x: get_initials(x['boxscore']) if x['week_int']==week_to_be_predicted else x['raw_data'],axis=1)
```

Where `df['week_int']` is a column of integers starting from 0 and increasing to 18. If the row value for `df['week_int'] < week_to_be_predicted` (in this case 15) I want the function `get_raw_data` to be applied, otherwise I want the function `get_initials` to be applied.

My question is in regards to troubleshooting the `apply()` function. The reason is that after successfully applying the `get_raw_data` to all rows where `week_int < 14`, instead of putting 0's for the remaining rows of `df['raw_data']` (else 0), the "loop" restarts, and it begins from the first row of the dataframe and starts applying the `get_raw_data` all over again, seemingly stuck in an infinite loop.

What's more confounding, is that it does not always do this. The functions as written initially solved this same problem, and have been working as intended for the past ~10 weeks, but now all the sudden when I set `week_to_be_predicted` to 15, it is reverting to its old ways.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with the `apply()` function, the conditions inside the apply function, or both. It's difficult for me to troubleshoot, as the logic has worked in the past. I'm wondering if there is something about `apply()` that makes this a less than optimal approach, and if anybody knows what aspect might be causing the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean mask:

```
def get_raw_data(sr):
    return -sr

def get_initials(sr):
    return sr

df = pd.DataFrame({'week_int': np.arange(0, 19),
                   'boxscore': np.random.random(19)})

m = df['week_int'] < week_to_be_predicted
df.loc[m, 'raw_data'] = get_raw_data(df.loc[m, 'boxscore'])
df.loc[~m, 'raw_data'] = get_initials(df.loc[~m, 'boxscore'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    week_int  boxscore  raw_data
0          0  0.232081 -0.232081
1          1  0.890318 -0.890318
2          2  0.372760 -0.372760
3          3  0.697202 -0.697202
4          4  0.400200 -0.400200
5          5  0.793784 -0.793784
6          6  0.783359 -0.783359
7          7  0.898331 -0.898331
8          8  0.440433 -0.440433
9          9  0.415760 -0.415760
10        10  0.599502 -0.599502
11        11  0.941613 -0.941613
12        12  0.039865 -0.039865
13        13  0.820617 -0.820617
14        14  0.471396 -0.471396
15        15  0.794547  0.794547
16        16  0.682332  0.682332
17        17  0.638694  0.638694
18        18  0.761995  0.761995
```

Comment: TypeError: Object of type 'Series' is not JSON serializable

The function get_raw_data() is expecting a list-of-lists as input from rows of 'raw_data'

Comment: I don't know about your function, I just demonstrate how you can apply two different functions on same dataframe without override data using a boolean mask. I can't neither guess the function signatures and their implementation.